# Changing NetBeans 7.0 UI language

Tags: netbeans

I know, that this problem has many times been discussed, but I stuck with it on Windows 7. When I add `-J-Duser.language=en -J-Duser.region=US` to `netbeans.conf` using notepad i get following allert:

[image: Alert]

After I restart my computer I get the same alert when modifying `netbeans.conf`. There is no process could use it launched.

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: Maybe NetBeans is opened when you edit the file?

Comment: I said that no process using this file are launched

Comment: Problem solved. Just need to locate it at another folder, to change it and then return it back.

Answer (score 13):

This is taken from [Tao's Sun Blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/tao/entry/set_netbeans_user_interface_language).

Launch notepad or WordPad as an administrator, use that to open the file, and then make the change. You won't need to move the file this way.

2. Permanent Solution

   Go to Netbeans installation directory, for example,

   ```bash
   C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 6.0.1\\etc
   ```

   Open `netbeans.conf` and find NetBeans default option line

   ```bash
   netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m \
       -J-XX:MaxPermSize=200m -J-Xverify:none \
       -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true"
   ```

   Add `-J-Duser.language=en -J-Duser.region=US` to the end of this line

   ```bash
   netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m \
       -J-XX:MaxPermSize=200m -J-Xverify:none \
       -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Duser.language=en \
       -J-Duser.region=US"
   ```